# laravel docker docker-compose asset not found

Tags: php, laravel, docker, web, root

I run laravel with docker-compose file.

If I don't use volume , laravel can't get asset and css

If I use a volume, laravel can get any asset folders and css too.

But if my teammate use a volume, all source codes become root instead of www.
So 500 error happens.
The docker file should be run as root first, become www before CMD.

How can I fix this?

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-    installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
libpng-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
locales \
zip \
jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
unzip \
git \
curl \
lua-zlib-dev \
libmemcached-dev \
nginx


RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && curl -L https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/5.3.4.tar.gz | tar xvz -C     /usr/src/php/ext/redis --strip 1 \
    && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --    filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www


# PHP Error Log Files
# RUN mkdir /var/log/php
# RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
#RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
COPY ./config/supervisord/conf.d/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Copy config
COPY ./config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

RUN chown www:www /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./start_script.sh"]

EXPOSE 9000

RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage
USER www

# Run php-fpm
CMD ["./start_script.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile_php8
    image: docker/laravel
    container_name: app
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment: 
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      SESSION_DRIVER: redis
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    volumes: 
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    depends_on:
      - db

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    image: docker/nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on: 
      - app

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```